# scipy.signal.lfilter in Python

Tags: python, matlab, filter, scipy, signals

I have used

scipy.signal.lfilter(coefficient, 1, input, axis=0)

for filtering a signal in python with 9830000 samples (I have to use axis=0 to get similar answer to matlab), compere to matlab

filter(coefficient, 1, input)(seconds),

it takes very long time (minus) and it becomes worse when I have to filtering  several of time. is there any suggestion for that? I have tried numpy as well same timing issue. Is there any other filter that I can received similar answers?

Comment: Which version of SciPy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: I think it is version 1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *ifilter* from itertools to implement a faster filter.
The problem with the build-in function  *filter*  from Python is that it returns a list that is memory-consuming when you are dealing with lots of data. Therefore, [itertools.ifilter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) is a better option because it calls the function only when needed.

Some other ideas depending on your implementation are:

1. If you are designing an FIR filter, you can apply convolve.
2. Or you can use correlation, to get faster results, because it uses FFT.